# How to set per-user VC++ Directories, but different for VC++ 2013 and VC++ 2015?

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild

On my machine, Visual C++ solutions are arranged in this hierarchy:

```
Projects
+-- expat2013
+-- expat2015
+-- zlib2013
+-- zlib2015
+-- MyApp
```

All of them are separate solutions.

When I build with Visual C++ 2013, `MyApp` must use `expat2013` and `zlib2013`. These directories are referenced in *VC++ Directories* of the *Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user* and *Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user* property sheets. This works well for me, and also the coworkers, some of whom prefer a different directory layout:

```
Devel
+-- Libs
|   +-- expat2013
|   +-- expat2015
|   +-- zlib2013
|   +-- zlib2015
+-- MyApp
```

They can just spell out their own directories in the *.user* property sheets.

Enter Visual C++ 2015.

Linking the *2013 libraries to the 2015 version of `MyApp` fails with

```
LINK : fatal error C1047: The object or library file 'D:\Projects\zlib2013\bin\zlib.lib' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries
```

This is the reason that separate builds of zlib and expat exist in the hierarchy.

What is the recommended way to reference different library directories depending on the version of Visual C++?

The problem is that the *Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user* and *Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user* property sheets are shared between Visual C++ 2013 and 2015; I can specify only one of the two directories for each library.

Note that `MyApp` is under version control. Hence, I cannot hard-code the full path to the libraries anywhere. I could hard-code the last path component, e.g., `expat2015`, if necessary, but I don't know where I could do so, and still give the coworks an opportunity to place the libraries wherever they want.

Comment: Having seperate directories for complete libraries per VS version seems odd. I cannot imagine the code is *so* different that it warrants duplicating that. Just having seperate project files is usually sufficient. Or are those directories just for libraries/binaruis built by the different versions and not the source code?

Comment: @stijn The library source code is actually the same.The only difference between the directories `zlib2013` and `zlib2015` is in the toolset referenced by the project files. (Ditto for `expat*`.)

Comment: Well just having seperate project files (which have different output directories) might be easier to maintain then. Or even having one common project file which is configurable via properties where needed, and which in trun gets imported in smaal 'stub' project files per toolset required.

Answer (score 1):

What you really should be doing isn't distinguishing between the VS version, but between the used toolsets: VS2015 can be used to build VS2013 projects using the same toolset so even though you're using VS2015 you'd still have to target e.g. expat2013.. However assuming you only use VS2013 to build with v120 and VS2015 with v140 toolsets, you can have msbuild select paths automatically by checking the `$(PlatformToolset)` property.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VsSuffix Condition="'$(PlatformToolset)'=='v120'>2013<VsSuffix >
  <VsSuffix Condition="'$(PlatformToolset)'=='v140'>2015<VsSuffix >
</PropertyGrop>
```

This goes into the project file (or much better, a common property sheet) after the location where a default generated project has the PropertyGroups setting the PlatformToolset. Then when declaring include directories etc you use

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ClCompile>
    <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>expat$(VsSuffix);zlib$(VsSuffix);%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
  </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

> The problem is that the Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user and Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user property sheets are shared between Visual C++
>   2013 and 2015.

Which is why arguably there are not the best fit for what you are doing with them. Not sure if you need it, but if you want devs to have custom settings per project and/or per VS version you can add Import lines like

```
<Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\$(ProjectName)\$(VsSuffix)\dev.$(Platform).props" Condition="exists('"$(UserRootDir)\$(ProjectName)\$(VsSuffix)\dev.$(Platform).props"')"/>
```

just below the \Microsoft.Cpp import lines. Also note this doesn't have to be in UserRootDir. What we do often is import custom props files from $(ProjectDir) (and make version control ignore them) so devs can keep all the work in one directory instead of spread over project directory and some directory under AppData.

Comment: The name `VsSuffix` is made up and not pre-defined, right? Is it possible to define new categories of directories in Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user?

Comment: Yes VsSuffix is just arbitrary. I don't understand what you mean with the last question, what is 'categories of directories'? Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user is just the name which the msbuild devs chose and happens to be added by default to each project file. You can use arbitrary names and arbitrary property sheet directories though.

Comment: I meant new alternatives to `<IncludePath>` etc. For example, something new like `<LibraryUserPath>`. But I see that there are `UserMacros`. That is probably what I was asking for in my last question.

Comment: Yeah you can put custom properties under UserMacros as that's easier to work with from withing the IDE.

Comment: I did not find a workable solution so far :-(. Hence, I took the easy way out and disabled _whole program optimization_ in the expat and zlib libraries. Now they are portable between toolset versions, and I do not need separate build directories for Visual C++ 2015.